# Python: Find maxima and discontinuities in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, maxima

I have a question related to finding maxima or more preciseley discontinuities in a `numpy` array?
My exemplary data looks for example like this

```
a = np.array([3,4,5,8,7,6,5,4,1])
```

In general, I am interested in every maximum/jump in the data. For array `a`, I want to detect the 8 since it is a maximum (growing numbers on the left side and decreasing numbers on the right) and the value of 4, since the data drops after this value. Until now, I have used `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`
with `np.greater` to detect maxima, but I am not able to detect these jumps/discontinuities. For the data I am looking at, only a jump towards smaller values can occur not the opposite. Is there an easy pythonic way to detect these jumps?

Comment: so jumps discontinuities are defined as a difference of more than 1 ? `np.diff(a)` may help you.

Comment: Let us assume for the moment that i can assing a threshold value which could be one.

Comment: @Jan there's a slight difference between `pythonic` and `numpyic`. I face that a majority of `numpyic` methods are more readable and faster that `pythonic` ones (like loops, comprehensions etc.)

Comment: @mathfux you are right. I think we are always looking for an numpyic solution since it is in most cases faster ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
threshold = 1
a = np.array([3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1])
discontinuities_idx = np.where(abs(np.diff(a))>threshold)[0] + 1
```

`np.diff(a)` gives the difference between every component of `a`:

```
>>> array([ 1,  1,  3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -3])
```

From then `np.where(abs(np.diff(a))>threshold)[0]` is applied to find where detected discontinuities are (above user specified `threshold` in terms of absolute difference). Finally, you may add `+1` to compensate for `n=1` difference idx if needed (see `np.diff` kwargs) depending on which side of the discontinuities you need to be.

```
>>> discontinuities_idx
>>> array([3, 8])
>>> a[discontinuities_idx]
>>> array([8, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like mathemathical analysis where you need to define some conditions like `a'(x)>0` or `a'(x)<0`. So you can mask them:

```
a = np.array([3,4,5,8,7,8,6,5,4,9,2,9,9,7])
mask1 = np.diff(a) > 0
mask2 = np.diff(a) < 0
>>> np.flatnonzero(mask1[:-1] & mask2[1:]) + 1
array([3, 5, 9], dtype=int64)
```

It returns indices of items where maxima is met.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import math
a = np.array([3,4,5,8,7,6,5,4,1])
MaxJump = np.diff(a)
print(MaxJump)
print(len(MaxJump))
MaxJump1 = []
for i in range (len(MaxJump)):
    MaxJump1.append(math.fabs(MaxJump[i]))
print(MaxJump1)
MaxJump3 = np.max(MaxJump1)
print(MaxJump3)
```